# Error Virtual Box Android Studio

Tags: android

Al Iniciar el S.O en virtual box me parece un error y no he encontrado la manera de solucionarlo.Alguien me podria aydudar ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O alguien sabe de que se trata ese error ?

Comment: Qué tipo de placa base utilizas?

Comment: Byron, es el emulador? no puedo asegurar que funciona en virtual box ya que cuando usaba eclipse siempre fallaba!.

Comment: Si es android porque no utlizas un emulador?